# Overriding the maximum value of a bigint datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, constraints

Could a database administrator override the largest value that a `bigint` datatype could hold (making it smaller than what is listed in the documentation)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you could put a check constraint on the column

example

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable
ADD CONSTRAINT chkMaxValue CHECK (SomeCol < 123456 );
GO
```

You could also use a trigger to restrict it but that is overkill

Answer (score 4):

no, but you can create a check yourself so values wont exceed a certain value, like this:

```
create table test_bigint(
my_value bigint check (my_value <100)
)
```